# PHP doing a SHA256 hash signature on a string

Tags: php, api, hash, rsa

I am trying to sign a string with the secret key I have, but it keeps failing. I am new to this and are just starting to understand it a little bit (encryption and base64). But I have been stuck at this point for three days now and have pulled out all of my hairs. I just dont get it.

The bit from the api is:

> **MD5 Digest**
> MD5 algorithm is used to perform a signature operation on the final string to be signed, thereby obtaining a signature hex result string (this string is assigned to the parameter sign). In the MD5 calculation result, letters are all capitalized.

> **RSA Signature**
> Users could use their private key to perform a signature operation (Base64 coded) to a MD5 digest by implementing SHA256 algorithm through RSA, after users getting the signature result string which is signed by MD5 algorithm.

All I have tried:

```
$echostr="SS...AD";
$api_key="17...e0";
$secret="EB....D";
$parameters="api_key=".$api_key."&echostr=".$echostr."&signature_method=HmacSHA256&timestamp=".$timeStamp;
$preparedStr=base64_encode(strtoupper(md5($parameters)));

$sign=rsa_hash_sign($preparedStr, $secret);
echo "1 ".$sign."<\br>";
$sign=HmacSHA256_Sign($preparedStr, $secret);
echo "2 ".$sign."<\br>";
$sign=GenerateDigest($secret);
echo "3 ".$sign."<\br>";
$binaryKey = decode($secret);
$sign=encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $preparedStr, $binaryKey, true));
echo "4 ".$sign."<\br>";
$sign=hash_hmac("sha256", $preparedStr, $binaryKey, true);
echo "5 ".$sign."<\br>";
$sign=base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', base64_encode($preparedStr), $secret,true));
echo "6 ".$sign."<br>";



$cURLConnection = curl_init('...');
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'sign' => $sign,
    'api_key' => $api_key
));
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'timestamp: '.$timeStamp,
    'signature_method: HmacSHA256',//RSA
    'echostr: '.$echostr
));
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$apiResponse = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);
var_dump($apiResponse);



function encode($data) {
    return str_replace(['+', '/'], ['-', '_'], base64_encode($data));
}

function decode($data) {
    return base64_decode(str_replace(['-', '_'], ['+', '/'], $data));
}

function GenerateDigest($requestPayload)
{
    $utf8EncodedString = utf8_encode($requestPayload);
    $digestEncode = hash("sha256", $utf8EncodedString, true); 
    return base64_encode($digestEncode);
}


function rsa_hash_sign($package, $privateKey) {
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->setHash("sha256");
    $rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
    $rsa->loadKey($privateKey);
    $hash = hash('sha256', $package, true);
    $signature = $rsa->sign($hash);

    $hexData = bin2hex($signature);
    $base64 = base64_encode($hexData);
    return $base64;
}



function HmacSHA256_Sign($preparedStr, $secret) 
{
 signature result string which is signed by MD5 algorithm.
    $hash = "";
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->setHash('sha256');                                            
    $rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
    $rsa->loadKey($secret);
    return  $rsa->encrypt($secret);
}
```

But every $sign I try is giving me "Secret key does not exist" back as error. This is my first time trying anything with encryption and I am so lost and dont know how to solve this.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a link to the documentation so we don't have to hunt around for it. Also, please include the full context of any errors/exceptions. At a minimum you should have the line number of the statement that triggered the problem.

Comment: Yes ofcourse: https://docs.lbkex.net/en/#error-code
And
https://github.com/LBank-exchange/lbank-official-api-docs/blob/master/API-For-Spot-EN/Trading%20REST%20API.md